# The letter d at the end of min and max value of double in java

Tags: java, double

While I am doing some exercise with double variable in java. I saw that 4.94065645841246544e-324d has the letter d at the end. Can someone explain it for me please ?

I was trying to look up on google a lot but anything can not be found.

Comment: [JLS-3.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) says (in part) *A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter `D` or `d` ([§4.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)).*